# Warning appears after adding Room to my project

Tags: android, android-room

I have added the following dependencies :

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$ROOM"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$ROOM"
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$ROOM"
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:$ROOM"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$ROOM"
```

and now I'm getting this warning :

```
warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor' less than -source '1.8'
```

I have tried googling it but couldn't find anything.  Any idea what should I change and why ?

Comment: IIRC, clean your project.

Comment: just tried it but I'm still getting the same warning.

Comment: Please take a look at this closely related SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48421708/room-build-warning

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling in Java 7 and the version required in this room version is Java 8.

Go to File... Project Structure...

Select the app module and in the main tab (properties) select Target Compatibility to 1.8