# Room build warning

Tags: android, android-room

I have Android Room Persistence library in project(version 1.0.0) and set compile options to 1.8. When project build finishes, i get this warning:

> Warning:Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor' less than -source '1.8'

Everything works fine, but this warning annoys me. How to remove it?

Adding this dependency dosn't remove warning and i don't use another architecture components.

```
"android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.0.0"
```

Comment: post your full dependencies

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Note: this answer is relevant to Kotlin based gradle projects that use the 'kotlin-kapt' plugin (kotlin annotation processor plugin), but should also be useful to Java based projects.)

This warning seems to be fixed in the latest version of the Room library.

I replaced:

```
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
```

with

```
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.0-alpha1"
```

and the warning went away.

BTW, for Kotlin projects, the warning message varies with the Kotlin version.

With Kotlin 1.1.0 it's:

> warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor' less than -source '1.8'

but with Kotlin 1.2.21 it's:

> warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ProcessorWrapper' less than -source '1.8'

The fix was the same in both cases.

Comment: I do not use kapt, but I updated the version to "1.1.0-alpha1" and the warning was gone. Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that it worked for you. :-)  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Everything works fine, but this warning annoys me. How to remove it?

Well, You need to disable lint check temporary (Not recommended), by adding these lines into `build.gradle`:-

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        tasks.lint.enabled = false
    }
...
}
```

Adding `"android.arch.lifecycle:common-java8:1.0.0"` will remove warnings for `lifecycle` not for `room`.

By the way, this is just a warning not an error. Ignore it until Google decides to support Java 8 like they did in lifecycle library.

Answer (score 1):

Updating room version from `1.0.0` to `1.1.0` gets rid of the warning.

So just have these following dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    def room_version = "1.1.0"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replaced:

"android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"

with

"android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"

Answer (score -1):

i have the same issue, but i fixed it by

replace

`annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'`

to

`annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0'`